# REST - Dropwizard with ant and ivy

Tags: rest, ant, ivy, dropwizard

It is not possible for me to use maven. Searching the web for a dropwizard tutorial without maven, but nothing found...

Does anyone knows a good tutorial to start with dropwizard using ant and ivy instead of maven?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use maven?

Comment: My team works just with ant+ivy, so maven stuff is not allowed. Dont ask why :-)

Comment: You can build dropwizard like any other java project. But I suggest not using it if you're not going to use maven as it will waste more time than it saves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like normal ant build and insert this targets:

```
    <target name="compile-server" depends="clean, resolve, echo">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" source="1.8" target="1.8" encoding="UTF8" destdir="${bin}" includeantruntime="false" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="ivy.path-server" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="resolve">
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml" conf="*" />
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.path-server" conf="server" type="jar,bundle" />
    <ivy:cachefileset setid="ivy.libs-server" conf="server" type="jar,bundle" />
    <ivy:retrieve conf="server" pattern="${lib.dir}/ivy/[conf]/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>

    <ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.path-client" conf="client" type="jar,bundle" />
    <ivy:cachefileset setid="ivy.libs-client" conf="client" type="jar,bundle" />
    <ivy:retrieve conf="client" pattern="${lib.dir}/ivy/[conf]/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>

    <ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.path-test" conf="test, test-meta" type="jar,bundle" />
    <ivy:cachefileset setid="ivy.libs-test" conf="test, test-meta" type="jar,bundle" />
    <ivy:retrieve conf="test, test-meta" pattern="${lib.dir}/ivy/[conf]/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
</target>
```

add/update this to ivy file:

```
    <configurations>
    <conf name="server" description="server runtime dependencies" visibility="public"/>
    <conf name="client" description="client runtime dependencies" visibility="public"/>
    <conf name="test" description="unit test configuration" visibility="private" extends="server,client" />
    <conf name="test-meta" description="sonar and jacoco" visibility="private" extends="test" />
</configurations>



<dependencies>

        <dependency org="org.jacoco" name="org.jacoco.ant" rev="0.6.4.201312101107" conf="test-meta->default">
            <exclude org="org.apache.ant" module="ant" />
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="org.codehaus.sonar-plugins" name="sonar-ant-task" rev="2.1" conf="test-meta->default">
            <exclude org="org.apache.ant" module="ant" />
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.11" conf="test->default"/>  <!-- for builds outside of eclipse -->  
        <dependency org="org.mortbay.jetty" name="servlet-api" rev="3.0.20100224"  conf="server->default" />
        <dependency org="io.dropwizard" name="dropwizard-core" rev="0.7.1" conf="server->default"/>
        <dependency org="io.dropwizard" name="dropwizard-jersey" rev="0.7.1" conf="server->default"/>
        <dependency org="io.dropwizard" name="dropwizard-servlets" rev="0.7.1" conf="server->default"/>     
        <dependency org="io.dropwizard" name="dropwizard-jetty" rev="0.7.1" conf="server->default"/>        
        <dependency org="io.dropwizard" name="dropwizard-validation" rev="0.7.1" conf="server->default"/>   
        <dependency org="io.dropwizard" name="dropwizard-configuration" rev="0.7.1" conf="server->default"/>   
        <dependency org="io.dropwizard" name="dropwizard-jdbi" rev="0.7.1" conf="server->default"/>     
        <dependency org="io.dropwizard" name="dropwizard-db" rev="0.7.1" conf="server->default"/>
        <dependency org="io.dropwizard" name="dropwizard-jackson" rev="0.7.1" conf="server->default"/>
     </dependencies>
```

Perhaps you have also the problem with io.dropwizard.jackson.Discoverable, then use this:

```
<!-- Dropwizard Hack for problem https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/455 io.dropwizard.jackson.Discoverable is used by seveal libs and is overwritten each time -->
<property name="dropwizard.hack.name" value="io.dropwizard.jackson.Discoverable" />

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/ivy/test/ant-contrib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<!-- Dropwizard Hack for problem https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/455 io.dropwizard.jackson.Discoverable is used by seveal libs and is overwritten each time -->
<target name="mergehack" depends="clean, unjar_mergehack">


    <!-- for every filename do another merge -->
    <var name="file.destination" value="${bin}/META-INF/services/${dropwizard.hack.name}" />
    <delete file="${file.destination}" />
    <touch file="${file.destination}" />
    <merge tofile="${file.destination}">
        <sourcefiles>
            <fileset dir="./${tmp}/dropwizard.hack/">
                <include name="**/${dropwizard.hack.name}" />
            </fileset>
        </sourcefiles>
    </merge>
    <!-- second one ... -->
    <!-- copy and change above -->
    <!-- third one ... -->
    <!-- copy and change above -->
</target>
<!-- = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
 macrodef: merge          
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = -->
<macrodef name="merge">
    <attribute name="tofile">
    </attribute>
    <element name="sourcefiles">
    </element>

    <sequential>
        <tempfile property="temp.file" prefix="ant.merge." deleteonexit="true">
        </tempfile>

        <concat destfile="${temp.file}" fixlastline="true">
            <sourcefiles>
            </sourcefiles>
        </concat>

        <copy file="${temp.file}" tofile="@{tofile}">
            <filterchain>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <linetokenizer>
                    </linetokenizer>
                </tokenfilter>
                <sortfilter>
                </sortfilter>
                <uniqfilter>
                </uniqfilter>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
<target name="unjar_mergehack" depends="clean, resolve">

    <!--  Needed for counting -->
    <var name="op2" value="1"/>
    <var name="op" value="+"/>
    <var name="opminus" value="+"/>
    <var name="result" value="0"/>

    <!--  What file should be searched in zipped file -->
    <var name="searchfile.name" value="${dropwizard.hack.name}"/>

    <for param="filename">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/ivy/server">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <math result="result" operand1="${result}" operation="${op}" operand2="${op2}" datatype="int"/>
            <!-- <echo>Result = ${result}</echo> -->

            <var name="destination" value="./${tmp}/dropwizard.hack/${result}"/>
            <echo message="1. Starting to read file: @{filename}" />
            <echo message="2. unzip to: ${destination}" />

            <unzip src="@{filename}" dest="${destination}">
                <patternset>
                    <include name="**/${searchfile.name}"/>
                </patternset>
            </unzip>
        </sequential>
    </for>
    <echo message="Ready" />
</target>
```

It unpack the libs seaches for the wanted files in each lib and then combines each data to only one file. This file is saved in your bin folder under META-INF/services/{filename}

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think there are more files like io.dropwizard.jackson.Discoverable, so this covers just a little part ...

Comment: Please correct me, if sth. is missing, but I think this is needed:

io.dropwizard.jackson.Discoverable, io.dropwizard.metrics.ReporterFactory, io.dropwizard.server.ServerFactory, io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory,
io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory and io.dropwizard.jetty.ConnectorFactory